# Will 26 x 2.0 tire fit on bicycle with 26 x 2.125 size tire

Tags: tire, rims

I am planning to purchase Maxxis Larsen TT 26 x 2.0 tire for my [Firefox Cyclone D 26](http://www.firefoxbikes.com/BikeDetails.aspx?BikeId=181) bicycle.

My bicycle currently has 26 x 2.125 tire. Just wanted to know if the above Maxxis tire will fit or not.

Comment: Almost certainly.  In our bike rehab work we regularly swap decimally-sized 26" tires across a fairly wide width range.  (Ie, we need a tire for a bike and we pick something "close" -- maybe replace a 2.125 with a 1.75.)  Never had a problem going smaller, though of course going larger you must worry about frame clearance.  And this doesn't apply to fractionally sized 26" tires (eg, 2 1/4), since they are weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It will work fine.

Judging by the description of the rims, it is likely they are Weinmann 519 or Zach 19s, or something very similar. Most of these generic double wall rims fall right around 19mm for inner width. This means they will comfortably hold a tire from 1.20" to 2.50". Many if not most big box store bikes use this size for that exact reason. There are a lot of readily available tire options and they are one of the more mass produced sizes so the cost of purchasing the rims as well as tires is cheap.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to be 100% sure as the link you provided does not provide the internal width of your rims.

However since you are going to a smaller tyre there should be no problems with frame clearance which makes it extremely likely the new 2.0 tyre will be fine