# Can I replace 700×23C tire with 700×28?

Tags: tire, road, size

I have Trek 1.1 with currently 700*23C tyres.

I need to replace them but the one available in market are 700*28

Can I use this size as replacement?

If yes, what'll be advantage and disadvantages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will 26 x 2.0 tire fit on bicycle with 26 x 2.125 size tire](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44235/will-26-x-2-0-tire-fit-on-bicycle-with-26-x-2-125-size-tire) and about a million other "will this size tire replace that sized tire" questions. Only difference is detail of width.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific brand of tire? You don't have to stick with the tires that came with your bike, you can often shop around for much better ones. This would allow for a much wider variety in widths (you'll still want to keep the diameter at 700).

Comment: Given its a road bike this question is more about frame clearances than whether 28 is an acceptable replacement for 23.   Your easiest option is to buy a single cheaper 28mm tyre and fit it, see how it goes.  I have about 1mm of clearance at the brake bridge on my road bike with 28, its only barely enough... but it is just enough.

Comment: @kenny.evitt The edit is reasonable but the question is still closed as a dupe.

Comment: @Criggie I know, but this duplicate was how I found the 'original' so I figured there was no harm in cleaning-up this 'sign post'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your rims can almost certainly take the extra width.  The real question is *can your frame, forks, and brakes?*  Only you can measure that.

Based on nominal dimensions (and some approximations) you would need an extra:

- 2.5mm either side to the chainstays/seatstays and forks/brake arches.
- 5mm above (to clear the brakes) and in front of the back tyre.

  A few bikes even have the front wheel very close to the downtube.  This assumes a very similar tyre to the one you have, just a bit bigger. You need to add a bit for safety margin, plus you need some clear air between the new tyre and the frame.  So do you have enough clearance around the tyre?

The 28 should give a slightly more comfortable ride, and may even be *more* efficient.  You'll need a slightly lower pressure.

Comment: On many road bikes the brake arch is also a sticking point (sometimes the main one).

Comment: @DeletedUser that's why I said "on top" but now I realise that could be interpreted as "additional" rather than "above". I was trying to avoid terms related to circle geometry. Plus there's the sides of the arch  I'll edit.

Comment: Correct.  I found that if you don't specifically call out the brake arch, people will forget to look in there.

Comment: @DeletedUser I'm quite tempted to say it would be a good idea to tape a couple of layers of cardboard to the existing tyre and see what they hit, if anything.